# How to get a particular item from Response Object havig 4 Items?

Tags: c#, response, dto

I am having Respone object which reurn 4 values.I need to get particular one detail alone.

```
 ResponseDTO responseDto = new ResponseDTO();

responseDto.ResponseObject = new
{
    ShippingPackageInfoList = shippingPacakgeInfo,
    IsDifferentLotNumber = diffLotNumber,
    IsDifferentLocation = diffLocation,
    IsPartMappedToTote = partTote != null
};
```

In this, I need to get shippingpackageInfo alone which is List and I need to iterate to access the values.

The ResponseDTO class Contains :

```
  public class ResponseDTO
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }

    public string UserMessage { get; set; }

    public string TechMessage { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    public object ResponseObject { get; set; }

    public bool RestrictApproveAction { get; set; }

    public bool IsAlreadyExists { get; set; }
}
```

I tried following method ,it returns null

```
IList<ShippingPackageInfoDTO> generatedShippingPackageList = generatedData as IList<ShippingPackageInfoDTO>;
IList generatedShippingPackageList = (IList)generatedData;
IEnumerable e = generatedData as IEnumerable;
IEnumerable<ShippingPackageInfoDTO> generatedShippingPackageList = e.OfType<ShippingPackageInfoDTO>();
```

Comment: How are you getting generatedData? Did you try with `generatedData.ShippingPackageInfoList` ? `responseDto.ResponseObject` seems to be set to an anonymous type

Comment: You might need to add some more information for us to help you. Which type is `generatedData` to begin with?

Comment: generatedData is responeDto which I returns from function call.ResponseDto is a class which having response object as object type,Added the code at top for reference

Comment: @Achu_L: See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the `ResponseObject` property to an anonymous object so this should work provided that `shippingPacakgeInfo` in your first code snippet is indeed an `IList<ShippingPackageInfoDTO>`:

```
dynamic responseObject = generatedData.ResponseObject;
IList<ShippingPackageInfoDTO> generatedShippingPackageList = 
    responseObject.ShippingPackageInfoList as IList<ShippingPackageInfoDTO>;
```